# WC Ukr Shipping displays the form with display:none

Tags: wordpress

For some reason, when the page loads, the form from the plugin is there for the first couple of seconds, then disappears, I have added additional styles, but it still doesn't work, how and where to configure it?

```xml
<div class="wcus-checkout-fields" style="display: none;"><h3>Вкажіть адресу доставки</h3> <div class=""><!----> <input type="hidden" name="wcus_np_billing_custom_address_active" value="0"> <div><p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required"><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="hidden" name="wcus_np_billing_city" value="8d5a9813-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567626"> <input type="hidden" name="wcus_np_billing_city_name" value="Кременчук"> <div class="zen-ui-select zen-ui-select-1"><div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><input type="hidden" value="8d5a9813-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567626"></div> <div class="zen-ui-select__value"><span class="zen-ui-select__value-text">Кременчук</span> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129"><path d="m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51, 51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6, 1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8, 1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z"></path></svg></div> <div class="zen-ui-select__dropdown"><div class="zen-ui-select__search"><input type="text" placeholder="Введіть значення для пошуку" class="zen-ui-select__search-input"></div> <div class="zen-ui-select__options"><div class="zen-ui-select__option">
          Київ
        </div><div class="zen-ui-select__option zen-ui-select__option--current">
          </div></div></div></div></span></p> <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field" style="display: none;"><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" name="wcus_np_billing_custom_address" id="wcus_np_billing_custom_address" placeholder="Введіть адресу" class="input-text"></span></p></div></div></div>
```

[image]

The output through the styles did not help, the inscription fill in the address does not allow you to buy the product

Answer (score 0):

I confronted the same problem. I've applied very robust solution, but it works (at least for me).

You can manually set "display: block" on .wcus-checkout-fields after 2 second after page load

This code worked for me, feel free to adapt it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready( ()=>{
    var counter_for_timeout = 1;
    while (counter_for_timeout < 5) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            jQuery('dd.variation-').each( (index, el) => {
                jQuery(el).find('p').contents().unwrap();
            });
            jQuery('div.wcus-checkout-fields').css('display', 'block');
        }, (counter_for_timeout*1500));
        counter_for_timeout = counter_for_timeout+1;
    }
});
```